# Updating Previous Screen state on back navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have a react native app and I have a use case where I need to update my previous screen based on the activity happened on current screen.
I go from ScreenA to ScreenB using navigation.navigate(RouteName.ScreenB, {parameters, handlers})
ScreenA --> ScreenB
Not I can do many things on ScreenB
Not that I passed some handlers to ScreenB for back communication.
So whenever a button Click happens on second screen. I do navigation.goBack(). Now the question is, when do I invoke those handlers ?
Should I invoke those handlers on button onClick that is closing the current screen and going back before/after navigation.back() statement ?
or
Should I invoke those handlers in componentWillUnmount lifecycle method.

```
Class ScreenB extends React.Components {
// this button click closes the current screen.  
onClick = ()=>{
    const {handlers} = navigation.route.params
    //invoke handlers, should I invoke them here ?
    navigation.goBack()
     //invoke handlers, or should I invoke them here ?
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount(){
      const {handlers} = navigation.route.params
     //invoke handlers, or should I invoke them here ?
  
  }

}
```

I want the behaviour where ScreenB reference should be completely removed and there should be no memory leakage as these handlers were passed from previous screen.

Note that for going back, I only have one way that is navigation.goBack(), I won't be able to use navigation.navigate(previousRouteName) as my every route has a unique randomly generated key which is not exposed to any other screen.

Answer (score -2):

Pass the current route `name` to the next screen and then use that and route `params` to pass data back to the previous screen.

Current screen

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'NextScreen',
  params: { previousScreen: route.name }
});
```

Next screen

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: route.params.previousScreen,
  params: { <data here> },
  merge: true,
});
```

See [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) for details.